# How to develop a Calculator using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to code a calculator in AngularJS but it isn't working.

Here is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>MIAGE Calculator</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 ">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Op. 1</label>
                    <input type="number" id="op1" class="form-control"/>
                    <label>Op. 2</label>
                    <input type="number" id="op2" class="form-control"/>
                    <label>Résultat</label>
                    <input type="number" id="resultat" readonly class="form-control"/>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <button type="button" class="form-control btn-primary" id="plus" ng-click="additioner()">+</button>
                            <br>
                            <button type="button" class="form-control btn-primary" id="moins ng-click="soustraire()">-</button>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <button type="button" class="form-control btn-primary" id="multi" ng-click="multiplier()">*</button>
                            <br>
                            <button type="button" class="form-control btn-primary" id="divi" ng-click="diviser()">/</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="form-control btn-success">Mémoriser</button>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="form-control btn-success">Charger la mémoire</button>

                    <label>En mémoire</label>
                    <input type="number" id="memoire" readonly class="form-control"/>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script >

    var app = angular.module("monApp",[]);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope){
    $scope.resultat = 0;
    $scope.op1 = 'op1';
    $scope.op2 = 'op2';

    $scope.additioner = function () {
        $scope.resultat = $scope.op1 + $scope.op2;
    };

    $scope.sousraire = function () {
        $scope.resultat = $scope.op1 - $scope.op2;
    };

    $scope.multiplier = function () {
        $scope.resultat = $scope.op1 * $scope.op2;
    };

    $scope.diviser = function () {
        $scope.resultat = $scope.op1 / $scope.op2;
    };

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

in order to access the values in the inputs you need data-binding, you should add `ng-model` , so replace :
`<input type="number" id="op1" class="form-control"/>`
with : `<input type="number" ng-model="op1" id="op1" class="form-control"/>`
and the same for `op2` and `resultat` 
ps : you forgot a quote after the `id="moins` and there's a typo in : `$scope.sousraire = function () ...` it should be `soustraire` instead of `sousraire`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this: I have created Simple Calculator:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
<style>
.parentDiv{
border-size:1px;
left:25%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black;
width:800px; 
height:400px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:   #ADD8E6;
} 
.welcomeNote{
font-size:30px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<title>CreatingAngularServices</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="parentDiv">

  <div>
    <span class="welcomeNote"><b>Welcome to AngularJs Calculator:</b></span> <br/> <br/>
      <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Enter First Number:
           </td>
           <td>
              <input type="number" ng-model="numberOne">
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Enter Second Number:
           </td>
           <td>
               <input type="number" ng-model="numberTwo">
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Your operation has result:
           </td>
           <td>
              <input style="background-color: yellow" type="text" ng-model="output"/>
           </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      </div> <br/> 
      <div>
          <button ng-click="plus()">Add</button>
          <button ng-click="subt()">Subtract</button>
          <button ng-click="mult()">Multiply</button>
          <button ng-click="div()">Divide</button> 
          <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button><br/><br/><br/>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>

 <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.service("firstService", function(){
        this.sum =  function(num1, num2){
            return num1 + num2;
        };

        this.subtraction = function(num1, num2){
            if(num1 > num2){
                return num1-num2;
            }
            else{
                return num2 - num1;
            }
        };

        this.multiplication = function(num1, num2){
            return num1 * num2;
        }

        this.division = function(num1, num2){
            if(num2==0){
                alert("dividend can never be zero");
            }
            else {
                return num1/num2;
            }
        }
    });

    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, firstService){
        $scope.plus = function(){
            $scope.output = firstService.sum($scope.numberOne, $scope.numberTwo);
        };

        $scope.subt = function(){
            $scope.output = firstService.subtraction($scope.numberOne, $scope.numberTwo);
        };

        $scope.mult = function(){
            $scope.output = firstService.multiplication($scope.numberOne, $scope.numberTwo);
        };

        $scope.div = function(){
            $scope.output = firstService.division($scope.numberOne, $scope.numberTwo);
        };
        $scope.reset = function(){
          $scope.numberOne="";
          $scope.numberTwo="";
          $scope.output="";
        }

    }); 

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```